# Is it possible to animate -webkit-text-fill-color?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate some text

```css
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
 color: black;
 animation: danger-zone 3s linear infinite;
 animation-direction:  alternate;
    font-size:60px;
  
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
}

@keyframes danger-zone {
 0% {

  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
 }

 100% {
  
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>Here's a title!</h1>
```

For some reason only the stroke appears to be animating, and the fill colour just switches at (I'm guessing) 50%. Is it possible to animate the fill colour in just CSS?

EDIT: It appears to work in Firefox, not Chrome. Gonna test some other browsers now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that chrome doesnt like the -color suffix, try this:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  animation: danger-zone 3s linear infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  font-size: 60px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
}
@keyframes danger-zone {
  0% {
    color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Here's a title!</h1>
```